# Java - Delete directory - IOException: Unable to delete directory

Tags: java

I'm trying to delete two repositories

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(jobInDirectory);
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(jobOutDirectory);
```

Path are right

Rights on directory too

The first is well deleted
but not the second. Every file inside was deleted but not the directory

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete directory /opt/appdata/conv/data/out/Job000000000676.
```

I looked to see if another process had locked it using the command `lsfo` and no other process uses it...

Any idea ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
on the repository /opt/appdata/conv/data/in everything works but not /opt/appdata/conv/data/out. They have the same rights.
In /opt/appdata/conv/data/out files are well deleted, just the directory dosen't.

My application has the same rights and in the same group of user i use in promtp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the following to fix this issue:-

1. User Id/account with which you are running your application must have permission to delete the below directory. If you are running the java application with your account then you must have permission to delete the below directory.

   ```
    /opt/appdata/conv/data/out/Job000000000676
   ```
2. Add the account into the proper group. To do that first check with `ls -ltr` execute it inside `/opt/appdata/conv/data/out`  and add your account to the group which has full permission to delete directories inside `out` directory
3. Also check if `Job000000000676` has sub directory inside it. In such a condition you can execute unix command like `rm -rf /opt/appdata/conv/data/out/Job000000000676`. See how to execute unix command from java application for detail.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
on the repository /opt/appdata/conv/data/in everything works but not /opt/appdata/conv/data/out. They have the same rights.
In /opt/appdata/conv/data/out files are well deleted, just the directory dosen't.

My application has the same rights and in the same group of user i use in promtp

Answer (score 1):

Did you check permissions on that directory/file to ensure the user executing the command has sufficient rights?

Alternatively, if another process has a handle on the file, that would also cause a problem.  Assuming you're using a linux based OS, try using the command: fuser /opt/appdata/conv/data/out/Job000000000676

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There are files in your folder ? If yes, you should delete them before delete the folder

Comment: deleteDirectory() will delete recursively as per documentation. If it wants empty folder to delete then what is the meaning of recursively? Rather I would use general file.delete() for empty folders.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, check if you are opening the file at any instance before deleting, maybe you are using a buffered reader for the same.
Ensure that file reader or buffered reader is closed before deleting.

Answer (score -2):

Pls check your disk space and keep enough space. Sometimes it is not able to perform IO tasks due to lack of space.